# How do I escape this ssh command correctly?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

So, I'm trying to run a command a couple of ssh hops away.
The command itself looks like this:

`ls /usr/local/patch/clone.example.com*|zip - -q@|base64`

This works fine when I've run it on an interactive shell, and I get my base64 encoded zip file.

However, when I run this:

`ssh -Aqt hop1.example.com ssh -Aqt hop2.example.com 'ls /usr/local/patch/clone.example.com*|zip - -q@|base64'`

I get back:
`zip error: Nothing to do! (-)`

As @shx2 noted, I get the same error if using just one `ssh` from a shell at hop1.

I should note that if I just run the `ls`, like this:

`ssh -Aqt hop1.example.com ssh -Aqt hop2.example.com 'ls /usr/local/patch/clone.example.com*'`

it does indeed give me the correct file list which I would like to see zipped. And again, if I run the whole thing on an interactive shell at the destination, it works great.

I've played around with this a ton, but I can't figure out how to escape this correctly so that it will work. Can anyone help?

Comment: why not pipe the output of the remote command to local commands? i.e. `ssh -Aqt hop1.example.com ssh -Aqt hop2.example.com 'ls /usr/local/patch/clone.example.com*' |zip - -q@|base64`

Comment: @shx2 because I'm not zipping the file names, I'm zipping the files themselves.

Comment: Assuming you work out all the quoting, the result is a script that is confusing and, thus, hard to maintain.  Copy a script to the remote tmp directory and invoke it with:  ssh remote 'bash /tmp/rmt ; rm /tmp/rmt'

Comment: @BruceK I agree, but unfortunately it has to work across many servers, and I cannot reliably add a script to all of them.

Comment: This zip command gives: `zip error: Invalid command arguments (cannot write zip file to terminal)`

Comment: @anubhava yes, but only if you do not pipe it somewhere else, in this case `base64`.

Comment: does it work if you only use one `ssh`? do you get the same error if you drop the `*`? What about using `/bin/ls` instead of `ls`?

Comment: @shx2 it does not work with only one ssh, and I do get the same error if I drop the `*`.

Comment: `ssh -Aqt anubhava@remote 'ls b*|zip - -q@|base64'` worked fine for me

Comment: @shx2 `/bin/ls` did not work either.

Comment: If you get the same error with a single `ssh`, why do you include nested `ssh` in your question? you only make it harder for people to answer the question

Comment: @shx2 fair enough, mostly because it prevents other solutions like just `scp`ing the zip file

Comment: Do you get files listed when you run: **`ssh -Aqt hop2.example.com 'ls /usr/local/patch/clone.example.com*'`**

Comment: @anubhava yes, I get the expected list of files

Comment: ok try: `ssh -Aqt hop2.example.com 'ls /usr/local/patch/clone.example.com*|base64'`

Comment: @anubhava that works fine and gives me the base64 encoded list of files

Comment: ok try: `ssh -Aqt hop2.example.com 'zip example  /usr/local/patch/clone.example.com*`

Comment: A couple of tips: one, don't pipe the output of `ls` to other commands, rather use the glob directory with `zip` (`zip - /usr/local/patch/clone.example.com*`). Two, rather than try to nest `ssh` commands like this, use the `ProxyCommand` option to specify how to reach `hop2.example.com` via `hop1.example.com`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks! But when I switch out the `ls` for the globbing in `zip`, I get the (base64 encoded) error `zip error: Invalid command arguments (cannot write zip file to terminal)`, though the command also works fine when I run it directly from a shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p hop1.example.com" hop2.example.com \
  'zip - /usr/local/patch/clone.example.com* | base64'
```

With the nested `ssh` commands, you need to quote the pattern *twice*, once so it isn't expanded on your local host, and again so it isn't expanded on hop1.example.com before being passed to hop2.example.com. Using the `ProxyCommand` avoids exposing the command to the shell on hop1.example.com. Also, passing the list of files to zip directly as argument is superior to reading the output of `ls`, which will break in the (rare) case where file names contain newlines, but also avoids the unnecessary extra process that runs `ls`.

If you connect to many different hosts through hop1.example.com, you might add ProxyCommand to your local `.ssh/config` file. This example shows how to set it up just for hop2.example.com, but you can specify a pattern that matches more than one host name, rather than a single host name.

```
Host hop2.example.com
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p hop1.example.com
```

Then, you can simply run

```
ssh hop2.example.com 'zip - /usr/local/patch/clone.example.com* | base64'
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great and I learned a lot about ssh best practices!

Comment: Follow-up question: is there a way to make this work when I only have the key for the hop1 server, and the hop1 server has the key for hop2?

Comment: I think you would just specify the key to use, with the `-i` option, in the command specified by the `ProxyCommand` option.